# AngularJS + IndexedDB, open database once for all controllers to use, or open it for each request separately?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexeddb

In using IndexedDB within AngularJS, I have this dilemma, as described in title, and not sure what would be the right way to go about it.

1. In many tutorials, database is being opened once, and that's it, all methods use that one connection.
2. In one AngularJS specific example, database opening request, as well as all CRUD methods are wrapped in a factory, and the controller as soon as it loads, calls the open method, and all CRUD methods are in this one controller.
3. I understood it's a good practice to keep controllers slim, to make them more reusable. So, I have separate controllers for each of the CRUD methods, which means I need a separate call for opening the database for each request, like so:

   ```
   websiteService.openDatabase().then(function() {
       websiteService.addWebsite($scope.website.url, $scope.website.color).then(function() {

       }, function(err) {
           console.log(err);
       });     
   });
   ```

So, everytime I want to `addWebsite`, I first `openDatabase` and wait for promise to resolve.

`websiteService` is a factory where all methods for working with IndexedDB are

What is the best practice here? If there's another way, not mentioned here, please do mention it.

If it helps, here's the complete controller code:

```
app.controller('AddWebsiteCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'websiteService', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, websiteService) {
    $scope.save = function() {
        websiteService.openDatabase().then(function() {
            websiteService.addWebsite($scope.website.url, $scope.website.color).then(function() {

            }, function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });     
        });     
        $location.path('/overview');
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $location.path('/overview');
    };  
}]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is unfortunately controversial.  I personally recommend opening the database each time. Others will disagree (and have, prolifically).

If you can guarantee your database requests will always occur *after* a connection is established, it would be ok to use a single connection. If you are unsure of how indexedDB works in various browsers, or cannot guarantee the connection has been established yet, or cannot guarantee the connection is still open, then open a connection for each separate task.

If you know how async code works in general, you are probably fine doing whatever you find best, as neither way is technically wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm a newbie to async code, so maybe this is naive, but I think if things are async, we can't really be sure the connection is always open. And going with a single connection has produced inconsistent results for me, while opening connection every time simply works. So my only remaining concern is - do you think this extra request each time would affect performance significantly? Or what's the main counter-argument of those who disagree?

Comment: To anyone interested, I think I found a way to make the code from my example a bit more DRY, by moving the call to OpenDatabase into the AddWebsite method in the websiteService (which is a factory).

Comment: I open a connection each time. In my experience, it does not significantly affect performance.